# I can't figure out how to print Hire and Fire from Stack

Tags: java, stack, queue

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Stack;

class Person {

private String name;
private String SS;

public Person(String N, String S) {
    this.name = N;
    this.SS = S;
}
}

class Manager {

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
private Queue<Person> app = new Queue<Person>();
private Stack<Person> hire = new Stack<Person>();
private Stack<Person> fire = new Stack<Person>();

public void Apply() throws QueueException {
    System.out.print("Applicant Name: ");
    String appName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("SSN: ");
    String appSS = keyboard.nextLine();

    Person apply = new Person(appName, appSS);
    app.enqueue(apply);

}

public void hire() throws QueueException {
    if (!app.isEmpty()) {
        hire.push(app.dequeue());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Nobody to hire.");
    }
     }

public void fire() throws StackException {
    if (!hire.isEmpty()) {
        fire.push(hire.pop());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Nobody to fire");
    }

}
}

public class Management {
public static void main(String[] args) throws QueueException,     StackException{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    Manager user = new Manager();
    boolean test = true;

    while (test){
        System.out.print("Press \n\t1 ACCEPT APPLICANT");
        System.out.print("\t2 Hire \n\t3 Fire \n\t4 Quit:");
        int action = keyboard.nextInt();
        String space = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (action == 1){
            user.Apply();
        }else if (action == 2){
            user.hire();
        }else if (action == 3){
            user.fire();
        } else if (action == 4){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Please try again.");
        }

    }
}

}
```

I can't figure out how I can print out the name and ssn of the person I just hired or fired. I tried using peek, but it's not working. Basically, the whole program is about whether to accept and application, hire or fire. If I accept an application, it will prompt for the user to enter their name and ss, and if I press hire/fire it should print out the name and ss of that person.

Comment: what is the problem exactly ? that's a lot of code to go through. please take the time to explain the problem you're facing in words.

Comment: Okay I sort-of went through the code and I still don't understand the exact problem, you have to print the hire and fire as you work on them ? or ...Remember... java.util.Stack RETURNS the item that was pushed or popped. So, you can store the item in a variable and print it out as you push it or pop it into/from the stack object. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: I just did another run for my program and when I hire someone, it goes through the whole process , but when I fire them it doesn't say anything that *person* is fired

Answer (score 0):

Youre defining the queue wrong.

Its more like: `Queue<Person> app = new LinkedList<Person>();`

and you need a print method.  Here's the Manager class.  The print is called in the the Management Class, and if you define `Manager user = new Manager();` you're surly going to be looked at funny.

Remove all the Throws.  They are not defined and are not used....

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

class Manager
{

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //private Stack<Person> app = new Stack<Person>();

    private Stack<Person> hire = new Stack<Person>();

    private Stack<Person> fire = new Stack<Person>();


Queue<Person> app = new LinkedList<Person>();

    public void Apply() 
    {
        System.out.print("Applicant Name: ");
        String appName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("SSN: ");
        String appSS = keyboard.nextLine();

        Person apply = new Person(appName, appSS);
        //app.enqueue(apply);
        app.add(apply);
    }

    public void hire() 
    {
        if (!app.isEmpty())
        {
            hire.push(app.remove());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Nobody to hire.");
        }
    }

    public void fire() 
    {
        if (!hire.isEmpty())
        {
            fire.push(hire.pop());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Nobody to fire");
        }

    }

    public void dump()
    {
        while(!app.isEmpty())
        {
           Person p = app.remove();
           System.out.println(p.getName()+"  "+ p.getSS());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Queue<Person> app = new LinkedList<Person>();` can't happen.

Comment: @Loraine why is that?  I did forget to add the getter and setter, but Press 
 1 ACCEPT APPLICANT 2 Hire 
 3 Fire 
 4 Quit:1
Applicant Name: ddd
SSN: 222
Press 
 1 ACCEPT APPLICANT 2 Hire 
 3 Fire 
 4 Quit:1
Applicant Name: ggg
SSN: 555
Press 
 1 ACCEPT APPLICANT 2 Hire 
 3 Fire 
 4 Quit:4
ddd  222
ggg  555